# Call function from stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Function:

```
  ---------Declarations
  DECLARE @OpStartTime datetime,
          @OpEndTime datetime,
          @OpRoomID uniqueidentifier,
          @OpRoomSortOrder int,
          @OpRoom varchar(200),
          @DayStartTime datetime,
          @DayEndTime datetime,
          @LastStartTime datetime,
          @LastEndTime datetime,
          @Count int

  SELECT @Count = 0

  DECLARE vendor_cur CURSOR FOR
      SELECT 
          @OperationStartTime, @OperationEndTime, @OperationRoomID,
          @OperationRoomSortOrder, @OperationRoom, 
          @StartWorkingDateTime, @EndWorkingDateTime

  OPEN vendor_cur

  FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cur
  INTO @OpStartTime, @OpEndTime, @OpRoomID, @OpRoomSortOrder, @OpRoom, @DayStartTime, @DayEndTime

  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN
      SET @Count = @Count + 1

      IF @Count = 1
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @ResultList 
              SELECT @OpRoomID, @OpRoomSortOrder, @OpRoom, @DayStartTime, @OpStartTime
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @ResultList  
              SELECT @OpRoomID, @OpRoomSortOrder, @OpRoom, @LastEndTime, @OpStartTime
      END

      SET @LastStartTime = @OpStartTime
      SET @LastEndTime = @OpEndTime

      FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cur INTO @OpStartTime, @OpEndTime, @OpRoomID, @OpRoomSortOrder, @OpRoom, @DayStartTime, @DayEndTime
  END

  INSERT INTO @ResultList 
      SELECT @OpRoomID, @OpRoomSortOrder, @OpRoom, @LastEndTime, @DayEndTime

  CLOSE vendor_cur
  DEALLOCATE vendor_cur

  RETURN
```

Stored procedure:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @ResultList TABLE 
                    (
                         RowId INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
                         OrRoomId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
                         OrRoomSortOrder INT,
                         OrRoom VARCHAR(200),
                         aStartTime DATETIME,
                         aEndTime DATETIME
                    )

  DECLARE
    @OST DATETIME,
    @OET DATETIME,
    @ORID VARCHAR(50),
    @ORroom VARCHAR(200),
    @ORSO INT,
    @ODSWDT DATETIME,
    @ODEWDT DATETIME

WHILE (@Date < @EndDate)
BEGIN
    SET @Date = @Date + 1

    SELECT
        @OST = Tblbooking.StartTime,
        @OET = Tblbooking.EndTime,
        @ORID = CTblOperationRoom.OperationRoomID,
        @ORroom = CTblOperationRoom.Code,
        @ORSO = CTblOperationRoom.SortOrder,
        @ODSWDT = DATEADD(HOUR, @StartWorkingHour, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Tblbooking.StartTime)),
        @ODEWDT = DATEADD(HOUR, @EndWorkingHour, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Tblbooking.EndTime))
    FROM
        OTS.TblBooking TblBooking 
    INNER JOIN 
        CSV.CTblOperationRoom CTblOperationRoom ON TblBooking.OperationRoomFK = CTblOperationRoom.OperationRoomID
    WHERE
        (@InstitutionID IS NULL OR CTblOperationRoom.InstitutionFK = @InstitutionID)
        AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, TblBooking.StartTime, 105), 23) = @Date) 
        OR (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, TblBooking.EndTime, 105), 23) = @Date)
        AND TblBooking.EndTime BETWEEN @OpStartTime AND @OpEndTime 
         OR TblBooking.StartTime BETWEEN @OpStartTime AND @OpEndTime
        AND ((@OperationRoomIDKey IS NULL) OR (TblBooking.OperationRoomFK = @OperationRoomIDKey))
      ORDER BY 
          Tblbooking.StartTime ASC

  --here is the code when I want to call the function
  INSERT INTO @ResultList 
      SELECT [OTS].[Function](@OST, @OET, @ORID, @ORroom, @ORSO, @ODSWDT, @ODEWDT) 

  IF(@Date = @EndDate)
      BREAK
END

SELECT * FROM @ResultList
```

Actually I want to call this stored procedure in order to get the session time between the date range. Nevertheless, I faced this issue when I called the stored procedure.

This is the error I get:

> Cannot find either column "OTS" or the user-defined function or aggregate "OTS.Func_VTblAvailableSlot_SessionTime", or the name is ambiguous.

Is there anyone who can help please!

Comment: Make up your mind. Your topic mentions "function" but you specifically say "want to call this store[d](sic) procedure". Nor does it help to post partial code. Noldy might have guessed correctly. If not, clarify and be consistent. Your cursor code looks highly suspect. It only selects variables, not columns from a table. There appears to be no reason to use a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
INSERT INTO @ResultList SELECT * from [OTS].dbo.[Function] 
(@OST,@OET,@ORID,@ORroom,@ORSO,@ODSWDT,@ODEWDT)
```